# JQuery to check if the user has inputted a specific letter or word within a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I'm having trouble trying to check if a user has inputted a specific letter or word(s) and if the letter or word(s) is correct then it will unhide a button.

Any help would be great!

This is what I have so far:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".textArea").keyup(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == 'a') {
       $(".continue").css("visibility", "visible");
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #3f2860;
}
.codeArea {
  width: 50%%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #ef6d3b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline-width: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.textArea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  white-space: normal;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.boxContainer {
  width: 98%;
}
.boxContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.continue {
  background-color: #ef6d3b;
  width: 6em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  height: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="codeArea">
  <textarea class="textArea">
    &#60;h1&#62;Test&#60;&#47;h1&#62; &#60;style&#62; h1&#123; &#125; &#60;&#47;style&#62;



  </textarea>

</div>

<div class="buttonContainer">
  <a href="#">
    <button class="continue" type="button">Continue</button>
  </a>


</div>
```

Comment: you mean to say jquery validation? reference: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be in the checking of the value in your textarea.  Right now you are grabbing all the text and seeing if it is `=='a'`.  Instead try something like this

`if($(this).val().indexOf('word') !== -1)`

Where 'word' is whatever you wanted to check for.  This will search for the text in the textarea and determine if it exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

In this block of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".textArea").keyup(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == 'a') {
       $(".continue").css("visibility", "visible");
     }
   });
 });
```

`$(this).val()` starts out with the value `<h1>Test</h1> <style> h1{ } </style>`, so will never be equal to 'a' unless you removed all the text and typed a single letter 'a'.

You need to be using `indexOf('a')` as such...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".textArea").keyup(function() {
     if ($(this).val().indexOf('a') !== -1) {
       $(".continue").css("visibility", "visible");
     }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are saying if the complete contents of .textarea equals a then show the button. Even it the contents contains a whitespace before and or after a it won't show the button.

If you want "show me the button when .textarea contains" then you need to make use of .indexOf()

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".textArea").keyup(function() {
         if ($(this).val().indexOf('a') !== -1) {
           $(".continue").css("visibility", "visible");
         }
       });
     });
```

Above example with your original code can be tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/m410xphk/8/

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Very helpful.

Comment: This code works perfectly but I need it to work if the user input 2 strings rather than just the 1.

Comment: this is what I have but it doesn't work:if ($(this).val().indexOf('text-decoration:underline;' && 'text-align:center;') == 1) {
      $(".continue").css("visibility", "visible");
    }

Comment: for some reason, if you type text-align:center; first it works on it's own. I need it so you have to type both in oredr for the button to display not just the 1 string. If that makes sense. Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try the link i've just posted? The textarea has to contain both strings before the contine button will appear

Comment: If it works, let me know. (and give an upvote to the approved answer as a thanks ;-))

Comment: unfortunately, the link you posted still only works if you just type text-align:center; It needs to be so you HAVE to input both strings and not just 1 to show the button.